# Selecionar e excluir registros duplicados por data da última atualização?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Entre os campos da tabela existe o campo nome, o campo dt_add que é a data que foi inserido o registro e dt_update que é a data da ultima atualização do registro.

Gostaria de saber como retornar e excluir registros repetidos, por exemplo se existir 100 registros com nomes iguais, excluir aqueles com data de última atualização inferior a 01/11/2017

---

**Explicando melhor:**

Em um sistema foi encontrado um problema que houve como consequência inserções vamos dizer de mais de 16 mil repetições para cerca de uns 100 registros com mesmo nome e valor em determinada tabela.

Parece surreal, mas mais de 16 mil registros duplicados para cada valor e o erro ocorreu com cerca de uns 100 valores. O erro foi percebido após análise devido ao alto consumo de recursos do servidor, e foi observado que o erro existe desde 2014 devido às datas de inserções e de atualizações dos registros.

O que vai ser feito é excluir todos aqueles que são repetidos com data inferior a 01/11/2017 a fim de amenizar o consumo de recursos e será feita a correção do sistema.

Não sei se consegui ser claro o suficiente para o contexto.

Em resumo necessito de um SQL `select` para retornar todos os registros repetidos e de um `delete` a fim de deletar os registros repetidos com data inferior a 01/11/2017.

---

**Sobre chave primária**

Tem chave primária sim, mas é uma tabela de configurações onde deveriam existir registros únicos (se não fosse este problema) e o sistema se baseia através da referência do nome da configuração e do valor.

Exemplo:

```
nome : habilitar-alertas 
valor: true 

nome : bloquear-clientes-pendentes 
valor: false
```

Comment: explique melhor o que precisa por favor, e coloque o código que está tentando fazer

Comment: Necessito de um SQL select para retornar todos os registros repetidos e de um delete a fim de deletar os registros repetidos com data inferior a 01/11/2017.

Comment: Tem chave primária essa tabela ? Ou só as 3 colunas citadas?

Comment: Na base de dados, as datas estão com tipo `date`?

Comment: São do tipo `datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Encontrei a resposta**

Vamos supor, todos os registros onde existam registros com mais de 2 repetições:

```
SELECT 
    nome, valor, dt_add, dt_update, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    configuracoes 
GROUP BY 
    nome
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 2 
ORDER BY 
    dt_update DESC
```

Para visualizar os registros ordenados por ID

```
SELECT 
    nome, valor, dt_add, dt_update 
FROM 
    configuracoes 
WHERE 
    nome = "habilitar-alertas"
 ORDER BY 
    id_configuracoes DESC
```

Deletar com ID inferior ao atual:

```
DELETE FROM 
    configuracoes 
WHERE 
    nome = "habilitar-alertas" and id_configuracoes < "id_mais_atual" ;
```

Comment: já estou postando a minha tb, dps dá uma olhada

Comment: esse código vai apagar todas as configurações com data inferior à especificada, isso vai dar errado...rs

Comment: Resolvi seguir seu conselho e não utilizar datas como referência rsrs

Answer (score 1):

Fiz a seguinte query:

```
  delete t.* from configuracoes t
     inner join (select 
c.nome,
c.valor,
c.date_add,
c.date_upd
from configuracoes c
where c.date_upd = (select max(x.date_upd) from configuracoes x where x.nome = c.nome)) x 
        where x.nome = t.nome and x.date_upd != t.date_upd;
```

O SQLFiddle não permitiu colocar o comando DML no lado da execução, mas funcionou perfeitamente no lado do schema.

> Resultado:

**Dados Atuais da tabela:**

[image: Dados atuais da tabela]

**Após a execução do Delete:**

[image: Após a execução do delete]

> *Importante:* Como você citou, é uma tabela de configurações e só deve ter uma linha para cada configuração, não fiz o delete com a condição da data ser menor que 01/11/2017 e sim, apagar todas que forem duplicados, e manter apenas a mais recente.

SQLFiddle Sem o comando delete: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7c474/2

SQLFiddle Após o comando delete: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16a37/1

Comment: Não entendi a lógica do SQL (falta de conhecimento meu provavelmente srsrs), mas o conselho de ir através do último ID fez com que a forma que utilizei desse certo